# parse json without title object in android

Tags: android, xml, json, api, rest

i have this json : `{"id":1,"name":"john smith"}`

How i can parse it? i know i have to do this with this function:

```
public static String parseJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {
    String name = "";
    JSONObject json;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONObject result = json.getJSONObject("**********");
        name = result.getString("**********");

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}
```

but i dont know what can i put in the areas incated with "**********". please help me

i only want to fetch `id` and `name` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this method to parse your JSON String

```
public static String parseJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {

    try {

         JSONObject  json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

           // get name & id here
         String  name = json.getString("name");
         int id =  json.getInt("id"); 

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}
```

For more Refer this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

parse current json String as:

```
json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
// get name here
name = json.getString("name");

// get id here
id = json.getString("id");
```

because current json string contain only one jsonObject

Comment: Correct ! What you put between these quotes is just the key to get a value from your JSON String

Comment: It was suggested from an edit that `json.getInt("id")` should be used to get the id.